# Numpy and linear algebra: how to filter an array without losing shape

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am implementing an mca algorithm as a learning exercise. My goal is to iterate through a matrix and 'turn off' rows and columns iteratively.

For that purpose, I have created a selector function.

```py
def minors(A):
    '''Creates a boolean list of selector arrays.

    Positional arguments
    ----------
    A: array-like
        An array or array like representing a matrix

    Returns
    --------
    selectors: list
        A list of boolean arrays corresponding to the selectors
    '''
    A = np.array(A)
    selectors = [] 

    for r, row in enumerate(A):
        for c, coef in enumerate(row):
            selector = np.ones(A.shape, dtype=bool)

            selector[r] = 0
            selector[0:len(row), c] = 0

            selectors.append(selector)

    return selectors
```

For a 3x3 matrix, this function will return a list of arrays starting at:

```
[
[False, False, False], 
[False,  True,  True],
[False,  True,  True]
]
```

And ending at:

```
[
[ True,  True, False],
[True,  True, False],
[False, False, False]
]
```

If I apply `A[selector]` I will get the desired selection from A, but the array loses it's shape (it gets flattened). For example, applying the first selector to a 3x3 matrix yields `[a22, a23, a32, a33]` for a in A.

Is there any way to do it while preserving the array's shape, such that applying the first selector to A would yield `[[a22, a23], [a32, a33]]`?

Comment: Don't use a boolean mask. Use index arrays.

Comment: If you always work with 3x3 matrices and 2x2 minors you can use `.reshape(2,2)` otherwise you can use logic to get the dimension of reshaping case by case

Comment: Since a boolean mask can have different number of `True` in each row or column, the indexing can't preserve shape - it has to return a 1d result.  Even in your case, some rows have 0 and others 2.  What if one row had 1? Obviously if you know something about selection, you can apply a reshape after.